# Negate bool app setting in Azure Function Proxies

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

I've got a bool app setting in my Azure Function called show_not_available_page:

```
"show_not_available_page": true
```

Depending on this setting I want to disable and enable proxy paths in proxies.json, e. g.:

```
"root": {
            "disabled": "%show_not_available_page%",
            ...
        },
```

This works fine but what I need additionally is a negation of the app setting value, something like  `"disabled": "NOT%show_not_available_page%"`

Is there a way to trigger the proxy paths with one app setting or do I need to add two app settings with opposite values?

Comment: Could you please let me know are you trying to disable the Azure Function Proxy local call?

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru-MT I'm not sure if I got your question right... The proxies.json consists of an array of config item and you can disable every config item with the "disabled" property. And I want to set this property with the (negated) value of an app setting.

Answer (score 0):

After having contacted the Microsoft support, the answer is:
It is not possible to change (negate) app setting values for the proxy.json.
That's why keep the workaround with two opposite app setting values:

"show_not_available_page": true,

"hide_not_available_page": false:

```
"root": {
            "disabled": "%show_not_available_page%",
            ...
        },
"notavailable": {
            "disabled: "%hide_not_available_page%",
            ...
        }
```